# Sending a SOAP Call

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I'm learning how to send and receive a SOAP call. I have the required parameters available with me like username , password and the URL of the WSDL/WebService.I lso know a sample SOAP reply that I'm expecting which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:infoLookupResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:vtsPhoneNumberLookup">
                    <phoneNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">4444444444</phoneNumber>
                    <Type xsi:type="xsd:string">Landline</Type>
                    <OCN xsi:type="xsd:string">2222</OCN>
                    <OVERALLOCN xsi:type="xsd:string">2103</OVERALLOCN>
                    <COMPANY xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC Inc</COMPANY>
                    <DBA xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC Inc</DBA>
                    <CommonName xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC</CommonName>
                    <HOLDINGCOMPANY xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC Communications Inc</HOLDINGCOMPANY>
                    <MANAGEMENT xsi:type="xsd:string"></MANAGEMENT>
                    <SMS xsi:type="xsd:string"></SMS>
            </ns1:infoLookupResponse>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have gone through online stuff and based on my understanding, in order to send the SOAP request, I need to have a raw XML of the same format that I'm 
expecting ( as mentioned above). The condition in my case is that a user will be submitting a phone number using an HTML Page and that will be sent as a SOAP
request expecting the aforementioned reply from the server.

In the above case, a user would have submitted 4444444444 as a phone number. So,I understand that I need to create raw XML type of phoneNumber and my questions is, do I need to create raw XML for Type,OCN,OVERALLOCN,COMPANY,DBA,CommonName,HOLDINGCOMPANY,MANAGEMENT and SMS as well?

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with what I have understood so far. Also, let me know if you would like me to paste some specific part of WSDL  which will help you in answering/understanding my question.

Comment: What language or platform are you using? In modern systems, you don't have to play with the XML.

Comment: I don't see namespace of `urn` of your response. Meanwhile I don't understand your question. Probably your created `WSDL`, `XSD` and implemented service in your code. So can you send and get request/response messages in `XML`. For `Type,OCN,OVERALLOCN,COMPANY,DBA,CommonName,HOLDINGCOMPANY,MANAGEMENT` and `SMS` elements specified in `XSD`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Im using Coldfusion 8 on Windows